# Stored procedure Insert After Insert

Tags: sql-server

I'm working on SQL Server 2008 and I have two tables:

- First: Born table with columns ID, Name, Address, Birth_Date
- Second: Citizen table with columns ID, Name, Income, Address

Now I want database to insert a row into `Citizen` whenever I insert a row into `Born`, which means I want to "insert into Citizen after insert into Born".

But I need it to be parameter so I don't have to do the same thing every time

I've added a stored procedure

```
Create proc CitizenBorn
As
Begin
    Insert into dbo.Citizen (ID, Name, Income, Address, Card_ID)
        Select 
            Id, Name, '0', Address, Card_ID 
        From 
            dbo.Born
End
```

But it didn't work, because I tried to insert row into "Born table" but it didn't affected "Citizen table"

Comment: Why don't you use a trigger on the `Born` table?

Comment: You want an AFTER INSERT trigger on the Born table, in which you use the data in the 'inserted' collection to populate the Citizen table.

Comment: Thanks WEI_DBA, Thanks pmbAustin, But I did that already, it also didn't work , and triggers are not parameters...Or I just don't know how is it work!  
  
    Create Trigger CitizenBorn On dbo.Born
After Insert
As
Begin
Insert into dbo.Citizen (ID,Name,Income,Address,Card_ID)
Select Id, Name,'0', Address, Card_ID From dbo.Born
End

Comment: What are you looking for as a parameter?

Comment: Yes, triggers are not parameters. But I have no idea why that's a relevant observation.  What do you mean by 'I need it to be a parameter" anyway? You need to use the inserted collection.  See the answer below. The values that are inserted into Born (whatever they are) will be inserted into the Citizen table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a trigger on Born to insert into the Citizen table with each insert into Born:

```
CREATE TRIGGER Born_Insert 
   ON  dbo.Born 
   AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    INSERT INTO dbo.Citizen ([ID], [Name], [Income], [Address], [Card_ID])
        SELECT [Id], [Name],'0', [Address], [Card_ID] 
          FROM inserted;
END
GO
```

Comment: That means you already have a row in Citizen for a row being entered in Born.  Which would seem odd, as it would seem there should be a one-to-one correspondence here. I would assume both tables have a primary key on ID.  Is it possible you just have some invalid test data in there?  Clear out both tables and try again?

Comment: Also keep in mind that with this trigger in place, you shouldn't be doing any manual inserts into the Citizen table anymore. Inserting into Born will auto-insert the required data into Citizen. Make sure you don't have code trying to do both anywhere.